# Use open firmware mode with external monitor (Powerbook G4)

Tags: display, powerpc, powerbook

I am trying to install Debian from USB to a Powerbook G4 with a broken screen. If I boot to the Mac, the external monitor works without problems. But in boot select mode (holding down 'alt' at startup) and Open Firmware (cmd + alt + O + F) the external monitor does not come on. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a magnet to trigger the lid closed switch (upper middle of the touchpad in my 17' model)

An external keyboard would have worked as well.